# SP 2013 Column Widths

Tags: 2013, form

I found the script below for controlling the width of a SP column elsewhere on this site. What SharePoint file would I insert this code in or can I just create a file with the code (and proper column name) and upload it to the SharePoint web site with an aspx file extension in one of the sub-folders? Thanks!

Use this javascript in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Name')").css("width", "300px"); //You can change the Column Name to be the column you want to change the width, Title in the code for example.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Will this work for columns in libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Script Editor or Content Editor webpart to add your HTML/Javascript code on your page.

Follow the steps given in below link to add your code in Script Editor:

[How to Use the Script Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2013](https://bamboosolutions.com/2013/05/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Will this work for columns in libraries?

Comment: Yes, if the selectors and code is correct it will.